# How to Post Array multidimensional angular js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array in angularjs, Example as below.

```
$scope.order.qty='20';
$scope.order.adress='Bekasi';
$scope.order.city='Bekasi';
```

This array can post with this code

```
$http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>add_order',
         data    : $scope.order,
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
         })
```

I can get all variable with

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$_POST['qty'];
$_POST['address'];
$_POST['city'];
```

But I'm confused if array multi-dimensional like this :

```
$scope.items[1].kode_produk='PR_1';
$scope.items[2].kode_produk='PR_2';
$scope.items[3].kode_produk='PR_3';
```

How to post and get variable from array multi-dimensional like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is one way

in JavaScript send data $scope.items, for example:

```
$http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>add_order',
         data    : $scope.items,
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
         })
```

and on the site PHP code write:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
var_dump($_POST); die();
```

and analyze the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass array like it:

```
$http({
      method  : 'POST',
      data    : { items: $scope.items }
      ...
     })
```

getting data:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$items = $_POST['items'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json will look like this if you send `$scope.items` :

```
[
  {
    "kode_produk": "PR_1"
  },
  {
    "kode_produk": "PR_2"
  },
  {
    "kode_produk": "PR_3"
  }
]
```

Which results to this php array after `$input = json_decode(...)`:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'kode_produk' => string 'PR_1' (length=4)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'kode_produk' => string 'PR_2' (length=4)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'kode_produk' => string 'PR_3' (length=4)
```

You have an array of objects, not a multidimensional-array!

You can iterate over the items like:

```
foreach($input as $item)
{
    echo $item->kode_produk;
}
```